# Make clustered dendrogram more readable in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, cluster-analysis, dendrogram

I would like to make a dendrogram to group countries that had similiar course of HICP index in the EU through 2000-2022. I can only use eurostat, dplyr and ggplot2 libraries except the basic R-ones.
I used hierarchical grouping of distances that are calculated with the "minkowski" method where p=1.5. Then I would like to make a dendrogram of it with 4 clusters. The graph should look like this:

How the dendrogram should look like:
[image: How the dendrogram should look like]

But I have trouble with displaying only the countries's names like in the example. My graph is very cluttered that is basically unreadable.

I used the data from eurostat library:

```r
install.packages("eurostat")
install.packages("dplyr")
install.packages("ggplot2")
library(eurostat)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

#Downloading the HICP dataset for EU
hicp <- get_eurostat("prc_hicp_manr", time_format = "date")
```

Filtering the time in the dataset from 2000-02-01 to 2022-09-01, then filter only CP00 basket of goods, then filtered the dataset to show the data for current 27 member states only additionally, replacing the iso codes with english names.

```r
member_states <- c("AT", "BE", "BG", "HR", "CY", "CZ",
                        "DK", "EE", "FI", "FR", "DE", "GR", 
                        "HU", "IE", "IT", "LV", "LT", "LU", 
                        "MT", "NL", "PL", "PT", "RO", "SK", 
                        "SI", "ES", "SE", "EL")


hicp_filtered <- hicp %>% filter(time >= as.Date("2000-02-1")
                               & time <= as.Date("2022-09-01")) %>%
                          filter(coicop == "CP00") %>%
                          filter(geo %in% member_states) %>%
                          mutate(geo = case_when(
                            geo == "AT" ~ "Austria",
                            geo == "BE" ~ "Belgium",
                            geo == "BG" ~ "Bulgaria",
                            geo == "HR" ~ "Croatia",
                            geo == "CY" ~ "Cyprus",
                            geo == "CZ" ~ "Czech Republic",
                            geo == "DK" ~ "Denmark",
                            geo == "EE" ~ "Estonia",
                            geo == "FI" ~ "Finland",
                            geo == "FR" ~ "France",
                            geo == "DE" ~ "Germany",
                            geo == "GR" ~ "Greece",
                            geo == "HU" ~ "Hungary",
                            geo == "IE" ~ "Ireland",
                            geo == "IT" ~ "Italy",
                            geo == "LV" ~ "Latvia",
                            geo == "LT" ~ "Lithuania",
                            geo == "LU" ~ "Luxembourg",
                            geo == "MT" ~ "Malta",
                            geo == "NL" ~ "Netherlands",
                            geo == "PL" ~ "Poland",
                            geo == "PT" ~ "Portugal",
                            geo == "RO" ~ "Romania",
                            geo == "SK" ~ "Slovakia",
                            geo == "SI" ~ "Slovenia",
                            geo == "ES" ~ "Spain",
                            geo == "SE" ~ "Sweden",
                            geo == "EL" ~ "Greece",
                            TRUE ~ geo
                          ))
```

Creating the dataset that shows only countries, time and HICP value

```r
hicp_uncluttered <- hicp_filtered[, c(3,4,5)]
```

the dataset now looks like this:
[image: the dataset now looks like this:]

Now, when the context is given I tried to code the dendrogram plot:

```r
values <- hicp_uncluttered[,3]

dist_matrix <- dist(values, method = "minkowski", p = 1.5)

hc <- hclust(dist_matrix)

dend <- as.dendrogram(hc)

plot(dend)
```

But I get resulting plot:
[image: But I get resulting plot]

How do I have to rewrite the code so there only countries are visible rather than values that I suppose generate such messy plot?

Comment: It looks like the data is in one long column, what you need to do convert your data to a wide format where each row is a country and each column is each month/year.  The perform the clustering.

Comment: Is there any way to do this without using the tidyr package? This is a university assignment and professor wants us to limit ourselves to basic R libraries and dplyr. I thought about using the t(hicp_uncluttered) but that simply transposes the whole dataframe

Comment: Try the `reshape()` function it is a part of the base stats package.